# Random Time Distribution using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in SQL Server (current data)

[image]

Total Over Time of EmpId 1001 in January-2020 is 3hrs 24 min

I want to distribute/add 3hrs 24min randomly between 1-jan-20 to 31-jan-20 to OutTime column

(expected result)

[image]

There are 200+ employees and different employees have different over time data (stored in another table)
How to I write a query to update the OutTime of those employee who has overtime

Comment: It will be great if you can show us your current query. Also kindly explain how do you want to `randomly` distribute the over time of `3hrs 24 min`. What are the rules ?

Comment: can you post the ddl and dml you have

Comment: Actually there are 2 tables where 1st table contain EmpId, PunchDate, InTime,OutTime (as shown in 1st image), whereas 2nd table contains 2 columns i.e. EmpId and OverTime.  I want to update OutTime in 1st table. For example employee 1001 has 3hrs 24min. I want to add this time to outTime but not on single day, it should be any random day and random hours/min. So at the end total 3hrs 24min get distributed completey. (as shown in 2nd image)
If we compare 1st and 2nd image above,there is difference of 3hrs 24min yellow highlighted. I want to write a query to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i write this code for your problems
this code work for one employee you can expand this code for all employee with one cursor or while.

this select is for generate sample data into temp table

```
SELECT *
INTO #DATA
FROM (
VALUES
(1001,'2020-01-01','09:14' , '06:45'),
(1001,'2020-01-02','08:20' , '06:15'),
(1001,'2020-01-03','07:14' , '06:20'),
(1001,'2020-01-04','09:30' , '07:00'),
(1001,'2020-01-05','09:20' , '06:30'),
(1001,'2020-01-06','09:14' , '06:40'),
(1001,'2020-01-07','08:45' , '06:10'),
(1001,'2020-01-08','08:30' , '07:45'),
(1001,'2020-01-09','08:14' , '07:15')
) AS F(EMPID , PURCHDATE,INTIME,OUTETIME)


-- the time must be add in random value is 3:24
DECLARE @AddedTime TIME = '3:24'
```

with this code convert your time as minute becare full about second in your time if you have second you will be add in this code and change all minute date part to second

```
DECLARE @AddedTimeAsMinute INT = DATEPART(HOUR , @AddedTime) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE , @AddedTime)
---------------------------------------------------------
PRINT @AddedMinute
---------------------------------------------------------
```

this part is for get min and max date and differente beween them for chose a random day between them.

```
DECLARE @DiffDate INT
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-01-01',@EndDate DATE = '2020-01-09'
SELECT @DiffDate = DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate ,@EndDate )
```

after that you can select one day as random and add a random minute to outtime

```
WHILE @AddedTimeAsMinute > 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @AddMinute INT= (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@AddedTimeAsMinute - 1))+1)

    SELECT *,CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,@AddMinute,OUTETIME) AS TIME) NEWTIME
    FROM  #DATA 
    WHERE DAY(PURCHDATE) = FLOOR(RAND()*(@DiffDate - 1 + 1)) +1
    AND EMPID = 1001

    SET @AddedTimeAsMinute = @AddedTimeAsMinute - @AddMinute

END
DROP TABLE #DATA
```

you can put the core of while loop into a cursor for any employee data

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly I am looking for. It worked! Accepting this answer. Thank you.

Just to know, an additional stuff, can we generate only numbers divisible by 5. 
this line  
`DECLARE @AddMinute INT= (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@AddedTimeAsMinute - 1))+1)`
I mean, minutes like 30, 55,25,20....

Comment: @shravanbardwa if you like my anwer please click upvote tank u.  you can change a part of code with this code `DECLARE @AddedTimeAsMinute INT = 204

DECLARE @AddMinute INT= (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@AddedTimeAsMinute - 1))+1)

WHILE @AddMinute % 5 <> 0
BEGIN

SET @AddMinute = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@AddedTimeAsMinute - 1))+1)

END

PRINT @AddMinute `